# Binary Search Tree c++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Please help me with this c++ code(I am beginner :P)
Its bugged... plz tell me where I am going wrong!
Note: I have used cout to debug...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
int val;
node* left;
node* right;
}*root;
void insrt(node* a,int n)
{
if(a==NULL)
{
    a=new node;
    a->val=n;
    a->left=NULL;
    a->right=NULL;
    cout<<"_";
}
else if(a->val>n)
{
    cout<<"<";
    insrt(a->left,n);
}
else
{
    cout<<">";
    insrt(a->right,n);
}
}
int main()
{
int n,x,i;
cout<<"Enter the size: ";
cin>>n;
root=NULL;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>x;
    insrt(root,x);
}
return 0;
}
```

It compiles and even runs but the output I get is:

```
Enter the size: 3
1
_2
_3
_
```

however it should be:

```
Enter the size: 3
1
_2
>_3
>>_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the value of `a` in `insrt` but that is only a copy of the input argument. Changing the value of `a` in `insrt` does not change the value of `root` in `main`.

One way to resolve this is to return the valid node from `insrt` and use it in `main`.

```
node* insrt(node* a,int n)
{
   if(a==NULL)
   {
      a=new node;
      a->val=n;
      a->left=NULL;
      a->right=NULL;
      cout<<"_";
      return a;
   }

   else if(a->val>n)
   {
      cout<<"<";
      a->left = insrt(a->left,n);
   }
   else
   {
      cout<<">";
      a->right = insrt(a->right,n);
   }
   return a;
}

int main()
{
   int n,x,i;
   cout<<"Enter the size: ";
   cin>>n;
   root=NULL;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
      cin>>x;
      root = insrt(root,x);
   }
   return 0;
}
```